# Copy line to clipboard in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: cmd, command, prompt, vanity

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\"%username%"\Downloads\vanity\gen
@echo off
set /p Address=""
vanitygen -X 0 1%Address%
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('vanitygen 1%Address% ^| findstr Privkey ') do echo %%a|clip
msg "%username%" Generation complete! Your private address has been copied to your clipboard!
PAUSE
```

This code works, however instead of copying the privaddress, it runs the script again, and copies that code. I need it to copy the first result, not the second one, as they will both be different. What can be done to make it only copy the one displayed?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('vanitygen 1%Address% ^| findstr Privkey ') do echo %%a|clip&GOTO DONE
:DONE
msg "%username%" Generation complete! Your private address has been copied to your clipboard!
PAUSE
```

It's difficult to figure out what you mean by "it runs **the** script again" - You havent indicated what `vanitygen` is, but if the string `Privkey` occurs more than once in its output, this change should fix the problem.